# Page link : easy with HTML but not with Java SWT

Tags: java, hyperlink, swt

I just want to do a simple link between two pages in Java SWT, like this HTML code.

page1.html :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>I'm on Page 1</p>
        <a href="page2.html"><input type="button" value="Go to Page 2"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2.html :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>I'm on Page 2</p>
        <a href="page1.html"><input type="button" value="Go to Page 1"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you give me the best way to do the same thing in Java SWT ?

Please note that I don't want to make a link to an HTML page. I want to make a link between two Java SWT views.

At this time, I have this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

    Composite composite = new Page1(shell, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setBounds(0, 0, 430, 260);

    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.class :

```
public class Page1 extends Composite {

    public Page1(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        Label lblPage1 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblPage1.setLocation(10, 10);
        lblPage1.setSize(80, 15);
        lblPage1.setText("I'm on Page 1");

        Button btnPage2 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnPage2.setLocation(10, 30);
        btnPage2.setSize(80, 25);
        btnPage2.setText("Go to Page 2");
    }
}
```

Page2.class :

```
public class Page2 extends Composite {

    public Page2(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        Label lblPage2 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblPage2.setLocation(10, 10);
        lblPage2.setSize(80, 15);
        lblPage2.setText("I'm on Page 2");

        Button btnPage1 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnPage1.setLocation(10, 30);
        btnPage1.setSize(80, 25);
        btnPage1.setText("Go to Page 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have two `Shell` that you want to switch between or do you have two "contents" that you want to switch between? It's not clear what you're asking for...

Comment: I have two contents that I want to switch between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two things you can do:

1. Use a `TabFolder` and have your individual contents in the tabs
2. Use a `StackLayout` and have your individual contents as separate layers in the stack

Here is an example for a `TabFolder`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    for (int i= 0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        TabItem tabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NULL);
        tabItem.setText("Tab " + i);

        Text text = new Text(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setText("This is page " + i);
        tabItem.setControl(text);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

And here is an example for the `StackLayout`:

```
private static int current = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Composite parent = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    final StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
    parent.setLayout(layout);

    final Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        buttons[i] = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        buttons[i].setText("Button " + i);
    }
    layout.topControl = buttons[0];

    Button switchButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    switchButton.setText("Show Next Button");
    switchButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            current = (current + 1) % buttons.length;
            layout.topControl = buttons[current];
            parent.layout();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Ok, here goes. Now you can switch through "pages" without a "master button":

private static int  current = 0;

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Composite parent = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    final StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
    parent.setLayout(layout);

    final Composite[] pages = new Composite[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
    {
        pages[i] = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        pages[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
        pages[i].setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            new Label(pages[i], SWT.NONE).setText("C" + i + " B" + j);

        Button goToNext = new Button(pages[i], SWT.PUSH);
        goToNext.setText("Go to next");
        goToNext.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                current = (current + 1) % pages.length;
                layout.topControl = pages[current];
                parent.layout();
            }
        });
    }

    layout.topControl = pages[0];

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. In your example you have a master button who switch the display of pages. I want that when you clic on the switch button, it clears all of elements (with the switch button) on the view. And after it displays the elements of the next page.

Comment: @user3780204 I updated my answer. But maybe what you're actually looking for is a [`Wizard`](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JFaceWizards/index.html).

Comment: Ok now it's work. I have edited my code with your example, I show you that in an answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

App.java :

```
public class App {

    static Composite parent;
    static StackLayout stackLayout;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setText("SWT Application");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        parent = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        parent.setLayout(stackLayout);

        //----------Page 1----------
        final Page1 page1 = new Page1(parent, SWT.NONE);
        page1.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        //----------Page 2----------
        final Page2 page2 = new Page2(parent, SWT.NONE);
        page2.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        //----------Vector----------
        final Vector<Composite> pageVector = new Vector<Composite>();
        pageVector.add(0, page1);
        pageVector.add(1, page2);

        //----------addLink----------
        page1.addLink(pageVector);
        page2.addLink(pageVector);

        //----------topControl----------
        stackLayout.topControl = page1;

        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.java :

```
public class Page1 extends Composite {

    Button btnPage2;

    public Page1(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        Label lblPage1 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblPage1.setLocation(10, 10);
        lblPage1.setSize(80, 15);
        lblPage1.setText("I'm on Page 1");

        btnPage2 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnPage2.setLocation(10, 30);
        btnPage2.setSize(80, 25);
        btnPage2.setText("Go to Page 2");
    }

    public void addLink(final Vector<Composite> pageVector) {
        btnPage2.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                App.stackLayout.topControl = pageVector.get(1);
                App.parent.layout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Page2.java :

```
public class Page2 extends Composite {

    Button btnPage1;

    public Page2(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        Label lblPage2 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblPage2.setLocation(10, 10);
        lblPage2.setSize(80, 15);
        lblPage2.setText("I'm on Page 2");

        btnPage1 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnPage1.setLocation(10, 30);
        btnPage1.setSize(80, 25);
        btnPage1.setText("Go to Page 1");
    }

    public void addLink(final Vector<Composite> pageVector) {
        btnPage1.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                App.stackLayout.topControl = pageVector.get(0);
                App.parent.layout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way to do a GUI structure. You can correct me.

Comment: Please don't use the answer feature to indirectly post a new question. Your code looks ok. Here are a couple minor suggestions: 1. Don't use `Vector` unless there's a good reason to. Use a `List` (or a synchronized version of it) instead. In addition, use [`Layout`s](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm) and don't set the size of widgets to a fixed value. You'll regret it in the future.